# Facebook API communication IP address and Port number

Tags: facebook

I have a website that has strict filters to allow any communication with other websites such as Facebook. Can anyone tell me what is the IP address and Port numbers for facebook REST and Graph APIs so that they can be allowed in my server..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should allow by DNS not by IP.  Facebook has something like 40,000 servers.

You'd want to allow

- *.facebook.com
- Ports 80 and 443

Comment: Thanks for the reply... 
I already tried allowing the following IP address but still not working.. 
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_IP_Addresses

I will give a try allowing the DNS and let you know if it worked..

Comment: I got a reply from server support saying "please note that firewall will work on OSI layer 3 and we can create rule based on IP address and not domain name." and they have white listed the IP ranges mentioned in wiki for ports 80 and 443... and it worked perfect!!

Comment: The wikipage seems down, could someone please post the iprange here?

Answer (score 0):

You better go to http://bgp.he.net/AS32934#_prefixes and got the total prefix of facebook.

Answer (score -3):

Facebook IP Address : 173.252.110.27

You can check it in your browser by typing like below.

https://173.252.110.27